# Chromes strange Behaviour position absolute and -webkit-transform: rotate

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, rotation, css-position

I explain it on an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/KW4CX/1/

If you click The Divs In Order: B -> C -> D -> E .... (or the other way around) it is working fine. But if you Skip one: A -> D it is not updating the X Value of the Divs.

Does Anybody knows a workaround ? Could also be in Javascript.

Code:
Html

```
<div class="col a"><span>A</span></div>
<div class="col"><span>B</span></div>
<div class="col"><span>C</span></div>
<div class="col"><span>D</span></div>
<div class="col"><span>E</span></div>
<div class="col"><span>F</span></div>
<div class="col"><span>G</span></div>
<div class="col"><span>H</span></div>
```

Js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.col').click(function(){
        $('.col.a').removeClass('a');
        $(this).addClass('a');
    });
});
```

Css

```
.col{
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;    
}

.col span{
    position: absolute;
    top: 1%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.col.a{width: 150px}
```

important is the ".col span" all the values are needed to reproduce this issue.